# How to call a UI function on a UICollectionViewCell once it has become visible

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a lovely UICollectionView living in a ViewController, with a custom class for the UICollectionViewCell. In each cell is an ImageView that uses a library to run an animated gif. The CollectionView is full width, so only one cell is visible at a time.

I need the gif to not appear and not start running until the containing cell is completely in view.  I know what function to call from the gif library in order to start/stop the animation. What I can't figure out is where/when to call that function.

All I can find are things that live within the CollectionView, so I'm calling them from the ViewController.  Things like calling my animation function in scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation in the ViewController, gets the following error:

> This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread after the engine was accessed from the main thread. This can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes.

I have set prepareForReuse in the CollectionViewCell, which temporarily "hides" the gif imageview (alpha 0), so at least there isn't a flash of another gif running when I scroll to a reused cell. But that doesn't take care of having the gif start animating AFTER the cell is totally visible.

Any help much appreciated :)

Edit: ok so this question didn't make a ton of sense.  Here's why: I misread an error message so was trying to solve a problem that existed in the library i was using, in addition to trying to fix things in my own code.  Solution was ... stop using that gif library as it has ISSUES, and switch to a different one that supports more of what I need.

Comment: So you only start running gif when the cell is completely in view, you can handle this in scrollViewDidEndDecelerating, calculate the current index based on the scrollview(collectionview offset) to start the correct gif.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try enabling paging on UICollectionView and then on UICollectionViewDelegate's method trigger animation after a delay:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
     DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.3) {
            // (cell as? CustomCell).animate()
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction :) Didn't solve the problem, but showed me where i was completely misreading an error message, so now I konw where the actual problem was.